# What does it mean geometrically that the diagonal cohomology class is concentrated along the diagonal?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes

In Milnor Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes*, the geometric interpretation of Lemma 11.8 on P125 is that the diagonal cohomology class is "concentrated along the diagonal". The lemma states that

> For any cohomology class $a \in H^*(M)$, the product $(a \times 1) \cup u''$ is equal to $(1 \times a) \cup u''$, in $H^*(M \times M)$.

Here, $u''$ is the "diagonal cohomology class", defined as in https://mathoverflow.net/a/74199/42662, or alternatively the image of the fundamental class of $H^n(M \times M, M \times M - \Delta(M)) \to H^n(M \times M)$.

How does the formal statement in the lemma give rise to the geometric "concentration" interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that if $\alpha, \beta \in H^*(M \times M)$ are two forms which are equal when restricted to the diagonal, then their pairing with the diagonal class $\int_{M \times M} \alpha u'' = \int_{M \times M} \beta u''$ are equal. So in a sense only the value of $u''$ when restricted to the diagonal counts. (You also need Poincaré duality to be able to say that knowing all pairings of $u''$ with all other classes is enough to know $u''$.)

Indeed, by Künneth's formula, over a field you have $H^*(M \times M) = H^*(M) \otimes H^*(M)$. So you can decompose $\alpha = \sum_i \alpha'_i \otimes \alpha''_i$ and $\beta = \sum_j \beta'_j \otimes \beta''_j$. The restriction to the diagonal is just the cup product: if $\delta : M \to M \times M$ is the inclusion of the diagonal ($\delta(x) = (x,x)$) then $\delta^*\alpha = \sum_i \alpha'_i \alpha''_i$ and similarly for $\beta$. Suppose $\delta^*\alpha = \delta^*\beta$. Then you get:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{M \times M} \alpha u''
& = \sum_i \int_{M \times M} (\alpha'_i \otimes \alpha''_i) u'' \\
& = \int_{M \times M} (\sum_i \alpha'_i \alpha''_i \otimes 1) u'' \\
& = \int_{M \times M} (\sum_j \beta'_j \beta''_j \otimes 1) u'' \\
& = \int_{M \times M} \beta u''.
\end{align}$$
Here I used $(a \otimes b) u'' = (a \otimes 1) (1 \otimes b) u'') = (a \otimes 1) (b \otimes 1) u'' = (ab \otimes 1) u''$.

Or for something more "geometric", if you work with smooth manifolds and differential forms: if you choose any neighborhood of the diagonal, no matter how small, you will be able to find a representative of $u''$ which vanishes outside this neighborhood.